# Programmatically Access a File on ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

As part of an ASP.NET MVC4 project I need to be able to read from and write to some XML files. I have trouble finding / accessing the files I need.

I've created a demo project to which I've added a folder `/Documents` containing some XML files.

So in the same project I have a folder `/Classes` with my class that should read the XML files using `XDocument.load()`.

Here is what I'd like to do (and how I thought it should work):

```
string path = "/Documents/test.xml"; // Doesn't work
XDocument xml = XDocument.load(path);
```

However, this doesn't work. Not with "/Documents", "Documents" or "~/Documents".
Supplying the full path works, but not very useful if the website is going to be deployed in other environments.

```
string path = "D:/Projects/Demo/Demo/Documents/test.xml"; // Works
XDocument xml = XDocument.load(path);
```

Any suggestions how I can access the files using some kind of relative path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to get the absolute path.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("/Documents/test.xml");
XDocument xml = XDocument.load(path);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Documents/test.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
var path = Server.MapPath("/Documents/test.xml");
```